# Como recuperar dados do componente Route do Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routes

Vi na [documentação](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) do Angular que é possível recuperar dados armazenados na propriedade `date` (que recebe um objeto) de uma `route`. Tenho, nesse caso uma aplicação com as seguintes rotas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'bank-accounts',
    component: BankAccountsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Contas correntes'
    }
  },
];
```

Como eu posso recuperar esses dados (o título, no caso) em uma rota?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oi,

Para recuperar os dados siga o exemplo abaixo:

BankAccountsComponent:

```
class BankAccountsComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => alert(JSON.stringify(v)));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Para mais detalhes veja o doc do Angular https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Veja tambem https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: depois eu pego a propriedade `sub` e faço `this.sub.title` para recuperar os dados, isso?

Comment: Para recuperar os dados voce deve armazenar a variavel v em uma variavel interna. 
Editei a resposta para dar um alerta mostrando o valor recuperado.